# I need assistance with using if statement with ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use ajax to toggle a button only if the response equals my condition,  i posted both of the code, This part `$('#uname_response').html(response);` of the code works fine,  my problem is with the `if` statement... thank you, I will appreciate if you guys can help me out with this... I have tried many things with no success

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#validationCode").keyup(function() {
        var username = $(this).val().trim();
        if (username != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajaxfile.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    username: username
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#uname_response').html(response);
                    if (response == "VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER.") {
                        $("#completebtn").show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#uname_response").html("");
        }
    });
});
```

Ajax File

```php
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";
       $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       $verifycode = $row['verification'];
       $response = "<span style='color: green;'>VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER.</span>";
       if($username !== $verifycode){
          $response = "<span style='color: red;'>CODE IS NOT VALID REQUEST FOR A NEW CODE.</span>";
       }
       echo $response;
       die;
    };
?>
```

Please if you have any answer please ask.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(response  == "VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER."){`

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the button you want to show with this If-check doesn't work?

That is because the `response` will contain the HTML tags also, so you would need to change the above to check for:

`<span style='color: green;'>VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER.</span>`

You can use `console.log(response)` in your JS-code and the inspector tool in your browser to see what the response actually is.

**A better soloution will be to apply the HTML with Javascript instead:**

Change in your PHP-file:

```
$response = "success";
if($username !== $verifycode){
    $response = "error";  
}
```

And change the Javascript to just check for the code:

```
if(response  == "success"){
    $("#completebtn").show();
    $('#uname_response').html("<span style='color: green;'>VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER</span>");
}
else if(response == "error") {
    $('#uname_response').html("<span style='color: red;'>CODE IS NOT VALID REQUEST FOR A NEW CODE.</span>");
}
```

Comment: I'd go with a mix - return "success=true/false" and the message combined as json - then the check as recommended here (but simple true/false) and build the HTML span in the js using the message provided by the service. This will allow for different server-side defined messages based on the cause of the fail (there may be more than one reason to fail). (+1'd this answer rather than add an almost duplicate answer - the principle is the same)

Answer (score 0):

it's OK!
on server side(php file) echo json encoded result like:

```
echo json_encode(['status' => "OK", "data_msg" =>'<span style="color: green;">VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER.</span>']);
```

and
in javascript or js file apply condition like:

```javascript
$.ajax({
        
        url:"ajax.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:data,
        beforeSend:function(){
        },
        success : function(data){
            if (button == 1) {
                 var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if(json.status == "OK"){
                        alert(json.data_msg);
                    }else{
                        alert(json.data_msg);
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Have a nice Day!

Comment: Thank you so much Sajjad Ali.. this also work but I find the other option more direct and short

Answer (score 0):

the problem resides in comparative statement of if

```
if(response  == "VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER.")
```

== will look for strict comparison, which some of the answer may have suggested to include whole tag as well, which is an over kill any ways.

**my solution**

```
 if(response.includes("VALIDATION CODE IS VALID COMPLETE TRANSFER")){ do what ever you want to do}
```

The includes() method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string. it returns true or false.

Keep it simple for your sanity sake.